# How do I find the total (Python)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dictionary

I want to loop through these dictionaries and find how much I would make if I sold everything in `stock`. This means I would have to multiply the items in `prices` by the items in `stock` and add the products I get. How do I do that using for loops?

```
prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}
```

Please keep your answers simple, I am only a beginner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answers are great, but not perhaps well-suited to beginners. Here's a much longer slightly slower bit of code that will help you understand...

```
amount = 0 # Used to increment your inv value
for eachKey in stock:
# Iterate through your stock, pulling values for each item you have
    try:
        amount += stock[eachKey]*prices[eachKey]
        # Try to add your total inventory price for the current iteration
        # to your total, but if that item in your stock has no price set...
    except KeyError as e:
        print("Your item {} has no price!".format(eachKey))
        # Let you know that there's no price for this item
print("Your total inventory has value ${:.2f}".format(amount))
# Print out your total inventory value
```

Comment: Please don't do this in practice.  Exceptions are for exceptional situations.  You can check whether the key is present without relying on an exception being thrown.

Comment: @adsmith Thanks! I found your answer MUCH easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You need to traverse the keys of either `stock` or `prices` dictionary, get the corresponding values of both dictionaries, multiply them and get the sum. That' s exactly what the provided piece of code does:

```
prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

print sum(prices[x] * stock[x] for x in stock if x in prices)
```

Upd: you can reduce the number of dictionary lookups if you will get the value from `prices` via the `get` method with the default value provided [as SimonC explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580865/how-do-i-find-the-total-python/20580885?noredirect=1#comment30788307_20580872):

```
print sum(prices.get(k, 0) * v for k,v in stock.iteritems())
```

Comment: 1. It will fail if the keys in `prices` is not superset of keys in stock
2. you can simply say `for x in stock`, it will be efficient

Comment: @thefourtheye +1 for both points, especially for the second.

Comment: This is not a very efficient way of solving this problem.  Please see my comments on thefourtheye's answer.

Comment: @SimonC yes, I see your point. I've updated my answer, thanks for the help!

Comment: @aga What does the `get` method do, and and what is `iteritems`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum` function to get the total.

```
print sum(v * prices[k] for k, v in stock.iteritems() if k in prices)
```

The above statement can be written as

```
total = 0
for k, v in stock.items():
    if k in prices:
        total += v * prices[k]
print total
```

Comment: Better still `print sum(v * prices.get(k,0) for k, v in stock.iteritems())`

Comment: @SimonC It will fail if the keys in prices is not a superset of keys in stock.

Comment: Calling `get` with a second parameter will return the second parameter if the key is not present.  This avoids an additional dictionary lookup.  The `iteritems` function avoids creating a list of all the key, value pairs.

Comment: @SimonC Yup, I get the `get` part but that is unnecessary. I took the `iteritems` point :)

Comment: Why do you say it's unnecessary?  You're currently doing two dictionary lookups for each key in `stock`.  Changing to `get` reduces that to one dictionary lookup per key.

Comment: @SimonC With dict lookup we are reducing one extra element being passed to sum.

Comment: true, but I think adding zero to a number is less of a cost than an additional dictionary lookup.

Comment: @SimonC Dictionary key lookup is O(1)

Comment: Right, what's your point?  Are you arguing that it's quicker than adding zero to a number?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43167/discussion-between-simonc-and-thefourtheye)

Answer (score -1):

A little bit close to production usage.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7


import types
from pprint import pprint as prn


class Store (object):

    def __init__ (self):
        self.__stock = {}

    @property
    def stock (self):
        return self.__stock

    @stock.setter
    def stock (self, products):
        """
        Args:
            products: {'<title>': [<quantity>, <price>[,
                       <...>}
        """
        if isinstance(products, dict):
            self.__stock.update(products)
        else:
            raise ValueError

    def income (self):
        stk = self.__stock
        return sum((stk[t][0]*stk[t][1] for t in stk))

    def __update (self, title, id, value):
        if title in self.__stock:
            self.__stock[title][id] = float(value)
        else:
            raise ValueError

    def update_quantity (self, title, q):
        self.__update(title, 0, q)

    def update_price (self, title, p):
        self.__update(title, 1, p)

    def remove (self, title):
        self.__stock.pop(title)


if '__main__' == __name__:
    st = Store()
    st.stock = {'banana': (6, 4)} # adding the new product

    # adding a group of new products
    st.stock = {'apple': [0, 2],
                'orange': [32, 1.5],
                'pear': [15, 3]}

    prn(st.stock)
    prn(st.income()) # calculating income

    st.update_quantity('apple', 1) # updating quantity for apples
    prn(st.stock)
    prn(st.income())

    st.remove('pear') # < removing pears
    st.stock = {'grape': [10, 2.5]}
    st.update_price('orange', 4.5) # updating price
    prn(st.stock)
    prn(st.income())


# >>> {'apple': [0, 2], 'banana': (6, 4), 'orange': [32, 1.5], 'pear': [15, 3]}
# >>> 117.0
# >>> {'apple': [1.0, 2], 'banana': (6, 4), 'orange': [32, 1.5], 'pear': [15, 3]}
# >>> 119.0
# >>> {'apple': [1.0, 2], 'banana': (6, 4), 'grape': [10, 2.5], 'orange': [32, 4.5]}
# >>> 195.0
```